# Reject hash from array of hashes based on a condition in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes like below.

```
[
   {
      "name":"keith",
      "age":"20",
      "weight":"100lb",
      "status":"CURRENT"
   },
   {
      "name":"keith",
      "age":"20",
      "weight":"110lb",
      "status":"PREVIOUS"
   },
   {
      "name":"keith",
      "age":"20",
      "weight":"120lb",
      "status":"FUTURE"
   }
]
```

I am trying to remove a hash based on the condition that if `name` and `age` are the same then fetch out the hash that has the `status` CURRENT ignoring the other statuses PREVIOUS and FUTURE. so the output should be

```
[
   {
      "name":"keith",
      "age":"20",
      "weight":"100lb",
      "status":"CURRENT"
   }
]
```

I have tried using `group_by` and `flat_map` but couldn't get the desired output.
Could someone please help me in figuring out this?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
arr.uniq { |h| [h[:name], h[:age]] }.select { |h| h[:status] == 'CURRENT' }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. This worked. But sorry my bad I forgot to mention one more condition in the question. 
that is if there are 2 hashes one with status FUTURE and the other with PREVIOUS then it should return both the hashes
Only if there is a hash with status set to CURRENT then all the others should be ignored

Comment: So I am using 
`arr.group_by {|h| "#{h['name']}_#{h['age']}"}.values.flatten.select{|h| h['status'] == 'CURRENT'}`
Is there any efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I couldn't understand the requirement. Can you give me an example of this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the problem (including the context added in the comments) the task is as follows:

- for any combination of (name, age) if we have an entry having `status == CURRENT` we should return this entry only
- otherwise, we should return the original entries as is

For example, for the data

```
data = [
  {
    "name":"keith",
    "age":"20",
    "weight":"100lb",
    "status":"CURRENT"
  },
  {
    "name":"keith",
    "age":"20",
    "weight":"110lb",
    "status":"PREVIOUS"
  },
  {
    "name":"keith",
    "age":"20",
    "weight":"120lb",
    "status":"FUTURE"
  },
  {
    "name":"alice",
    "age":"20",
    "weight":"120lb",
    "status":"PREVIOUS"
  },
  {
    "name":"alice",
    "age":"20",
    "weight":"120lb",
    "status":"FUTURE"
  },
]
```

the result of the operation described above should be

```
[
  {:name=>"keith", :age=>"20", :weight=>"100lb", :status=>"CURRENT"},
  {:name=>"alice", :age=>"20", :weight=>"120lb", :status=>"PREVIOUS"},
  {:name=>"alice", :age=>"20", :weight=>"120lb", :status=>"FUTURE"}
]
```

(so for (keith, 20) we return only a hash where status == CURRENT, for (alive, whatever) we return initial data unchanged).

The solution seems to be very straightforward:

1. Group by (name, age)
2. For each group if it contains an entry (hash) with status == CURRENT return just this entry, otherwise return the whole group as is.

Or the same in Ruby:

```rb
data
  .group_by { |name:, age:, **| [name, age] }
  .reduce([]) do |acc, (_, group)|
    current = group.find { |status:, **| status == "CURRENT" }    
    current ? acc.push(current) : acc.concat(group)
  end
```